# Ember: setting a controller's property in a route not working

Tags: ember.js

I have a user model and a user hasMany 'recordings'. On the user page, I would like to be able to paginate the user's recordings. My router looks like this:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @.resource 'user', path: '/:user_id', ->
    @.route 'page', path: '/page/:page_id'
```

I want to set the selectedPage property in the UserPageRoute like so (the page number is hard-coded for simplicity here):

```
App.UserPageRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: ->
    @.controllerFor('recordings').set('selectedPage', 3)
```

That seems to work. I can inspect the property while debugging my route code and the property seems set:

```
@.controllerFor('recordings').get('selectedPage') => 3
```

If I visit a user page directly (/user/25/page/3) and debug the RecordingsController, selectedPage no longer seems set.

```
@.get('selectedPage') => undefined
```

**Here is a jsbin illustrating the issue**:
http://jsbin.com/owudUgI/20/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not working as expected is somewhat subtle.

The issue is that while `selectedPage` is being correctly set on the singleton instance of the `RecordingsController`, the actual list of recordings being rendered in the `recordings` template is wrapped in a separate, new `RecordingsController` where `selectedPage` is not set.

Why is this happening?

There are two ways to call the `render` helper in a handlebars template. If you pass a single parameter, the named template will be rendered with the corresponding singleton controller as the context.

If you pass two parameters, the named template is rendered with *a new instance* of the corresponding controller with its content set to the second parameter passed.

So you are ending up with two `RecordingsController` instances: the singleton instance that `selectedContent` is set on, and a second one that the `recordings` template is rendered with.

To fix this, you need to change two things. First, change your render call to

```
{{render 'recordings'}}
```

Second, explicitly define a `UserRoute` so that you can set the content of the singleton `RecordingsController` whenever a new `User` is set:

```
App.UserRoute = Em.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    @_super controller, model
    @controllerFor('recordings').set 'content', model.get('recordings')
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @justin! I was confused because I read that controllers were singletons in ember, but I did feel like there were two different instances. Glad to see that this can work.

Comment: could you explain what the call to @_super is for? The jsbin seems to work without it.

Comment: Sure: `@_super` calls the method you are overriding in the parent class so that the default behaviour is applied. In this case, the default implementation of `setupController` calls `controller.set('content', model)`. You could do this explicitly but calling `@_super` is better in case the default implementation changes in the future.